# Нижнее и верхнее меню

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbar

Доброго времени суток!

Пордскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать такую штуку.

У меня есть android-приложение, в котором в главной активити находится ListView. 
Я хотел бы, чтоб над ListView была верхняя панель, которая показывалась бы постоянно, а под  Listview нижняя панель с несколькими кнопками, которая показывалась бы при выделении одного из элементов Listview.

Вопрос вот в чем:

Я могу это реализовать, тупо разместив LinearLayout с кнопками над ListView и еще один LinearLayout с другими кнопками под listview и показывать его, когда мне это нужно. Но мне кажется, что это очень топорное решение.

Может, можно сделать как-то лучше? Слышал что-то про ActionBarActivity, но, насколько я понимаю, там может быть только одна панель - та, что сверху, а я бы хотел и сверху, и снизу по панели. Есть ли какие-то подходящие варианты для этого, кроме как городить лейауты с кнопками вручную?

Спасибо!

Comment: это совершенно не топорное решение, а вполне нормальное.

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте [тут](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/action-bar-menus-and-splitactionbar-using-actionbarcompat-library-in-android/), кажется, это то что вам надо.

Если кратко:

1) Делаете обычное меню для ActionBar.

2) В манифесте нужной активити даёте атрибут:

```
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

Так можно отобразить элементы меню в нижней части. Чтобы их прятать\убирать можно назначать видимость элементам меню.

---

В качестве верхней панели можно саму ActionBar/Toolbar юзать.